# How to link progress change event to progress bar

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have windows form application that run a a class method by BackgroundWorker.

I would like to add the windows form a progress bar to show the progress.

in the class method I have  a foreach loop so I would like each loop to send the form event

with the current percentage.

this is what i do :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Parsser inst;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            inst = new Parsser();
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        }


        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.textBox1 != null & this.textBox2 != null)
            {
                if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
                {
                    // Start the asynchronous operation.
                    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
                }
            }
        }



        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            inst.init(this.textBox1.Text, this.textBox2.Text);

            inst.ParseTheFile();
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Parsing finish successfully");

        }
        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender,                ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

    }


}
```

`

and in the class i do this-

```
public Parsser()
    {
        bgReports = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgReports.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    }

    public void ParseTheFile()
    {
        Lines = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath);
        this.size = Lines.Length;
        foreach (string line in Lines)
        {

            bgReports.ReportProgress(allreadtchecked/size);
```

from some reason it dont work any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass reference of `BackgroundWorker` to `Parsser` and then using that reference call `ReportProgrss` method

```
BackgroundWorker worker;

public Parsser(BackgroundWorker bg)
    {
        worker = bg;
    }

public void ParseTheFile()
{
    Lines = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath);
    this.size = Lines.Length;
    foreach (string line in Lines)
    {
        worker.ReportProgress(allreadtchecked/size);
```

Comment: I change the code and I send the backgroundWorker1 to the Parsser constractor . and in the parsser class i call bgReports.ReportProgress(allreadtchecked/size); and try to catch this event by private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged but still it never get to the private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged

Comment: This answer still uses a second BackgroundWorker, bgReports. You REALLY shouldn't have 2 classes sharing a worker, nor should you have a second worker.

Comment: so what should be the answer?

Comment: I have an answer i've written. Certainly sharing the BGworker between classes would work, I just feel like it's a confusing and limiting design choice. It looks like Harris had edited the code since my response, so what he has should work, but again, having two classes splitting responsibility for setting up, starting, reporting progress, and ending a worker is difficult. The class would not be reasonably testable.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a duplicate BackgroundWorkder instance in the Parsser class constructor. Try below

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        inst.init(this.textBox1.Text, this.textBox2.Text);
        inst.ParseTheFile(backgroundWorker1);
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Parsing finish successfully");
    }
```

In the Parsser Class.

```
    public Parsser()
    {
        //Don't initialize backgroundworker here.
    }

    public ParseTheFile(BackgroundWorker bgWorker)
        {
            bgReports = bgWorker;
           .....
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a lambda or method to your worker method:

in form:

```
public void Run()
{
   myParse.DoWork(a => UpdateProgressBar(a.Progress));
}

private void UpdateProgressBar(int progress) { ... }
```

in Parser:

```
public void Parse(Action<ProgressArgs> onProgress)
{
   // do your job
   // invoke onProgress whenever needed
   onProgress(current / total * 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your background worker to do work via the `DoWorkEventHandler`. Also, it looks like each half of your partial class is using its own BackgroundWorker. You need to use the same reference. You have bgreports and backgroundWorker1.

```
backgroundWorker1.DoWork += MyMethod;


// ......


private void MyMethod(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Also, why are you testing your textboxes for null? Are you trying to test their text string contents for null? if so, I would use String.IsNullOrEmpty.

I think a better design here would be for your "Parsser" (please fix spelling and identify what type / purpose this class is for Opertional code) to define its own events that your consumer class would subscribe to. A parser shouldn't be responsible for running itself asynchronously. A consumer should have the choice of running something synchronously or asynchronusly. In either of those cases, custom progression events can be defined and subscribed (again, optionally).